# postgres login asks for non superuser password

Tags: postgresql

I set up postgres according to the instructions for Windows 10 but every time I try to run `psql` it asks for a non superuser password which I haven't created. How do I make it ask for the superuser without using `psql -U postgres` command every time? Or how can I set/change a password for a non superuser? I've tried using `ALTER ROLE` to change the password but get `role [username] does not exist` as an error message.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `psql` tries to use your OS username as a database username. Presumably this role hasn't been created in your database, hence the "does not exist" error.

You can override this default by setting the `PGUSER` [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).